# Javascript array variables not behave equally

Tags: javascript, xml

Javascript code reads XML local file into array variable arrTst. It works in Firefox 25.0.1 and I can see arrTst values in debugger. I have problems working with this arrTst. Example is displaying alert.

If I swap alert lines (displaying arrTest first) then alerts are not displayed.

Can anyone explain why alerts are not displayed when lines are swapped ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<inData>
    <record>
        <date>2012-08-01</date>
        <amount>7</amount>
    </record>
    <record>
        <date>2012-08-02</date>
        <amount>22</amount>
    </record>
</inData>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"> </script>
<title>test read XML file</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1 >Test XML</h1>
<div id="TstMsgArea"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var str1="";
var arrTst=[];
var arrCon=[["2013-08-01", 1], ["2013-08-02",33]];

$(document).ready(function(){ 
 /*******************************************************************
 * read xml file from local filesystem & push to array
 *******************************************************************/ 
     $.get("test.xml",{},function(xml){
        $('record',xml).each(function(i) {
            _date = $(this).find("date").text();                
            _amount = parseInt($(this).find("amount").text());

            var X0=[];
            X0.push(_date);
            X0.push(_amount);
            arrTst.push(X0);

            alert (str1);
            str1+=_date +", "+_amount+"; ";
            $("#TstMsgArea").append(str1);
        });
    }); 
/*******************************************************************
 * check array values - if lines swapped no go !
 *******************************************************************/ 
    alert ("arrConst : " + arrCon[0][0]+", " + arrCon[0][1]+";    " + arrCon[1][0]+", " + arrCon[1][1]); 
    alert ("arrTest : " + arrTst[0][0]+", " + arrTst[0][1]+"; " + arrTst[1][0]+", " + arrTst[1][1]);

});  //$(document).ready
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alerts are in the wrong place. You need to put them *inside* your success function, or in another function that you call from *within* that function.

Also, you shouldn't declaring `str1` and `arrTst` outside the success function. Those are values you are building up inside that function, and they won't be available outside of it.

If you want to use those variables somewhere else in your code, you need to put the code that uses them inside a function somewhere. Call that function from inside your `$.get()` success function, and pass it the variables as an argument. Then you can be sure that the data is ready.

```
var arrCon=[["2013-08-01", 1], ["2013-08-02",33]];

$(document).ready(function(){ 
 /*******************************************************************
 * read xml file from local filesystem & push to array
 *******************************************************************/ 
     $.get("test.xml",{},function(xml){
        var str1="";
        var arrTst=[];
        $('record',xml).each(function(i) {
            _date = $(this).find("date").text();                
            _amount = parseInt($(this).find("amount").text());

            var X0=[];
            X0.push(_date);
            X0.push(_amount);
            arrTst.push(X0);

            alert (str1);
            str1+=_date +", "+_amount+"; ";
            $("#TstMsgArea").append(str1);
        });
        alert ("arrConst : " + arrCon[0][0]+", " + arrCon[0][1]+";    " + arrCon[1][0]+", " + arrCon[1][1]); 
        alert ("arrTest : " + arrTst[0][0]+", " + arrTst[0][1]+"; " + arrTst[1][0]+", " + arrTst[1][1]);
    });

});  //$(document).ready
```

Comment: Point is I need this array outside the success function. And I also see values as expected in debuuger, outside of the success function. How could I do this ?

Comment: Read up on JavaScript asynchronous calls. The problem you're having is that you are trying to use the data before it's ready. Put some `console.log()` calls in your code, both inside the success function and at the end of your code where you have the alerts. Also remove all your alerts and change them to `console.log()`. Now look closely at the order in which the log messages appear. You'll see that you're trying to access the data before it's ready.